# Verify $\lim _{r \rightarrow +\infty} r ^ {\lambda} \int _{0}^{\pi / 2}{\rm e}^{-r \sin \theta} \text{d} \theta=+\infty$ for every $\lambda > 1$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Set
$$
I(r) = \int _{0}^{\pi / 2}{\rm e}^{-r \sin \theta} \text{d} \theta,
$$
it is proved that $I(r)<\dfrac{\pi}{2}r^{-1}$ as $r \rightarrow +\infty$
(in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2229462/evaluating-lim-r-to-infty-int-0-frac-pi2-e-r-sin-theta-d-theta)).

And I want to verify that for every $\lambda > 1$, $\displaystyle \lim _{r \rightarrow +\infty} r ^ {\lambda} I(r)=+\infty.$

Comment: The limit is $0$ by Dominated Convergence Theorem.

Comment: Use the inequality $\sin\theta \le \theta$ so $e^{-r\sin\theta} \ge e^{-r\theta}$ for $r>0$ and $\theta \in [0,\pi/2]$.

Comment: @geetha290krm The limit is actually infinite. Dominated convergence theorem does not apply here.

Comment: @Anne Bauval The limit is actually infinite. Dominated convergence theorem does not apply here.

Comment: @ChristopheLeuridan I've edited my question, "the limit" that he said refers to $\lim I(r)$

Comment: @ChristopheLeuridan geetha's comment and mine (now deleted) refered indeed to [the first version of this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/revisions/4614703/1). Now, why don't you post your first comment as an answer? Such kind of incomplete answers often happens on MSE.

Comment: @AnneBauval Just because it is a hint, and not a complete answer. I want to let Qetuo_233 work by himself.

Answer (score 4):

Expanding on @Christophe Leuridan's comment, we have
$$
I(r) \ge\int_{0}^{\pi/2}{\rm e}^{-r\theta} \text{d}\theta, ~\text{ i.e. }~ rI(r) \ge 1-{\rm e}^{-r\pi/2}
$$
thus
$$
\lim _{r \rightarrow +\infty} r^{\lambda}I(r)=+\infty.
$$